# Getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource issue using node with localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/data. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

The client side and server side code are both pretty simple:

Server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/data', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Client:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('http://localhost:3000/data', {}, function(data){
      $("#demo").html(data);
    });
  });
```

I understand this is a very general issue so I searched for the existing question and answers but none of them quite worked for me as far as I have tried. And both Chrome and FF have the same issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Comment: What is the complete url of file that contains the javascript code?

Comment: I'm guessing you are loading the web page into the browser from the file system which the system calls a `null` origin.  Make sure and load it from a `http://localhost:3000/somepath` URL.